# Rails mail interceptor only for a specific mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, interceptor

I have an interceptor : `DevelopmentMailInterceptor` and an inititializer `setup_mail.rb` that initiates the interceptor.

But I want to apply it to a specific mailer (to intercept `NotificationMailer` and not the other ones.

So I set in `setup_mail.rb` :

```
`NotificationMailer.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor)
```

But then all mailers get intercepted, as if I'd written

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor)
```

How can I filter this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution by exploring in depth the `message` parameter of the `delivering_email` method of the mailer interceptor.

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)

    filteredMailers = %w[
      NotificationMailer
    ]

    if filteredMailers.include?(message.delivery_handler)
      message.subject = "[filter] To:#{message.to} - #{message.subject}"
      message.to = 'logs@mail.com'
    end

    return message
  end
end
```

@Intrepidd's answer remains true since the interceptor is applied to the whole `Mail` class but I found the way around to what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Still relevant in 2018, I'm wondering if this is mentioned somewhere in the docs

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Interceptor are registered on the global `Mail` class (see the source of register_interceptor)

If you need your interceptor to be effective only on specific e-mails, you should add a condition inside the interceptor class.

Comment: Can't I have a default parameter to the `mail` method in the `ActionMailer` to talk to the interceptor?