# delivery_handler attribute of (ActionMailer) message object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, interceptor

Could anybody explain to me where can I find specific explanation about what is the attribute **delivery_handler** ? What kind of object ? A string ? or whatever ?

and how this instruction work :

```
filteredMailers.include?(message.delivery_handler)
```

I took it from this mail observer [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408376/rails-mail-interceptor-only-for-a-specific-mailer) :

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)

    filteredMailers = %w[
      NotificationMailer
    ]

    if filteredMailers.include?(message.delivery_handler)
      message.subject = "[filter] To:#{message.to} - #{message.subjec}"
      message.to = 'logs@mail.com'
    end

    return message
  end
end
```

I found this [reference](http://rdoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message) for the message class, but it's still very confused about what kind of object is delivery_handler.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented at https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/2.6.1/lib/mail/message.rb#L138

You're supposed to assign a class to it that implements a `deliver_mail` method that can/should do any of the following (quoted from the link above):

```
# * Appending the mail object to Mail.deliveries as you see fit.
# * Checking the mail.perform_deliveries flag to decide if you should
#   actually call :deliver! the mail object or not.
# * Checking the mail.raise_delivery_errors flag to decide if you
#   should raise delivery errors if they occur.
# * Actually calling :deliver! (with the bang) on the mail object to
#   get it to deliver itself.
```

Instead of calling `deliver!`, you could also call `yield`, which will tell Mail to call its own private `do_delivery` method.

ActionMailer assigns it the mailer class (i.e. MyMailer in `class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base`) [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.5/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb#L60), which then relies on `ActionMailer::Base`'s implementation of `delivery_mail` (unless you choose to override it).